# Use of ng2-table plugin in Angular 10 application shows error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement ng2-table grid (https://valor-software.com/ng2-table/) in my Angular 10 application. After implementing while compiling the application it shows the bellow compile time error:

> ERROR in
> node_modules/ng2-table/components/table/ng-table-filtering.directive.d.ts:1:36
>
> - error TS2724: Module '"../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?
>
> 1 import { EventEmitter, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
> ~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5964:31
> 5964 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
> ~~~~~~~~~
> 'Renderer2' is declared here.

Can anyone suggest how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that ng2-table module is not currently supported by Angular 10. Renderer is deprecated and now must be replaced by [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) since Angular 9.

In short in order to fix it you need to replace all constructors dependencies of Renderer with Renderer2 and ensure that all referenced methods exists

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a different table module since the original ng2-table package seems to have been discontinued (no update since 2016). It has over 350 forks though, there may be one of them that was updated for Angular 9+.

Comment: Repeating an accepted answer isn't polite

Comment: Nor isn't replying to a comment just to boost your reputation. Especially since my answer and the accepted answer barely have anything in common.